# Double Display of jQuery Mobile Elements

Tags: jquery-mobile, double, displayobject

I am having the problem that when I use $load I need to add the jQjs in the html-file I want to load. This results in double displays of my jQ elements..

When I dont have the js in my html file I am loading from it doesn't display in jQ style, but when I do it displays twice.. I have no idea how to fix this. :(

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you have jQ and jQM in `head` of first page opened, you don't need to add jQ and jQm in `body`, however, you can add them to `head`. Anyway, they will be neglected since `$load()` loads `body` only.

Comment: I have jQ and jQM in <head> of first page. But it doesn't load jQ when I do $load.. :(

Comment: How do you navigate between pages?